# Trying to convert xml to pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Please help me to convert an xml file to a pyspark dataframe.
Below is code I have written:

```py
import pyspark as ps
spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read \
.format("sample.xml") \
.option("user", "hierarchy") \
.option("rowTag", "att") \
.load("sample.xml")
print("df", df.show())
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o27.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Failed to find data source: sample.xml. Please find packages at
https://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedToFindDataSourceError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:574)
```

Comment: Does the file `sample.xml` exist in the same directory as your python script?

Comment: yes, it is in same directory

Comment: you have multiple references to 'sample.xml' on the same line of code, it may be useful to split that line for debugging. My guess would that your current working directory is not the directory where your script and the XML file are located.

Answer (score 0):

Just use instead your format

```
df = spark.read.format('xml').load("your path")
```

or

```
 df = spark.read.format('com.databricks.spark.xml').load("your path")
```

and check xml version you have installed,**spark-xml_2.12:0.13.Jar file**
Hope it will work.

Comment: getting this as output df <pyspark.sql.readwriter.DataFrameReader object at 0x0000025FC68C9A20>    how to see the data

Comment: `df.show()` ,, i think just try it.